# How to Bulid vlc-qt on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiling

I have followed the following steps.

1.Downloaded the source code as

```
git clone git://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt.git
Cloning into 'vlc-qt'...
remote: Counting objects: 4785, done.
remote: Total 4785 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 4785
Receiving objects: 100% (4785/4785), 3.14 MiB | 833.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3121/3121), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

2.Creating build Directory.

```
mkdir build
```

3.Going to build Directory.

```
cd build
```

4.Using make Command as

```
ajeet@administrator-OptiPlex-3040:~/vlc-qt/build$ **cmake ..DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug**
  -- Building VLC-Qt 1.2.0
  -- Git revision: 9b2f561
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Build statically: OFF
  CMake Error at config/Dependencies.cmake:29 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindQt5Quick.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Quick",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Quick"
  (requested version 5.2.0) with any of the following names:

    **Qt5QuickConfig.cmake
    qt5quick-config.cmake**

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Quick" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Quick_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Quick" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (INCLUDE)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/ajeet/vlc-qt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have tried to debug the issue and find the some solutions like `sudo apt-get install qt*5-dev` but this not work for me.

Any help and suggestions will be Appreciated Thanks in advance

Comment: And what exactly was the output of `sudo apt-get install qt*5-dev`? Apt uses regular expressions to search package names. Maybe you meant `sudo apt-get install '^qt.*5-dev$'`?

Answer (score 4):

CMake tells you that you're missing the `Qt5QuickConfig.cmake` file, that is part of the `qtdeclarative5-dev` package (found using [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Qt5QuickConfig.cmake&mode=exactfilename&suite=zesty&arch=any)).

Compiling `vlc-qt` requieres some more packages which can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev libvlccore-dev libvlc-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of build from source, [`vlc-qt`](https://vlc-qt.tano.si/#download) also offering Ubuntu packages which you can install easily. However you'll need to add ppa as it wasn't listed in official repository (3rd Party Repository).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ntadej/tano 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libvlc-qt
```

Comment: I know this is old, but it seems this ppa is down for some reason. Would you maybe know how to install libvlc-qt on Bionic?